# J48 Handling Missing Value with Tree based Imputation

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, weka, java

Aloha,

currently i have some trouble and question zu implement some kind of special missing value handling in WEKA J48 algorithm using WEKA JAVA API.

I want to test the performance of SHAPIRO approach zu handle missing value with imputation by using a decision tree to predict the value. Therefore, a separate decision tree for each attribute is needed. For a better understanding of my apporach, i had made a pseudo code: http://s7.directupload.net/images/140725/r4492x8v.png

My first problem: When i want to use the training data and set the class index to a continuous attribute, because of some missing values in, J48 cant work with continuous classes. So i have to discretize first. How can i discretize the training data in java code using WEKA API? The second problem: How can i change the class index of the training data after reading it? I only know how to do that during reading. Because i have du switch them to all attributes with missing in it and build decision trees.

Thanks for your help!